# Google Actions does not work from OK Google. my app is not recognised

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

I have downloaded this basic example from google: 
https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin

Now if I do:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://fit-actions.firebaseapp.com/start"
```

It will start my app. And the deeplink is being recognized.
The example shows that I can do this by saying in Google Assistant:

```
Start running in fit actions
```

Now I do this, but this only gives me Google search responses, it does not start my app similar to the adb shell command.
I did change the package name, so that it complies with my `google-services.json` file.

What am I doing wrong?

This is what I have in my Manifest:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateUnchanged">
        <!-- Required to support search action intents from Google Search -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.actions.SEARCH_ACTION"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Define your supported deeplinks -->
        <intent-filter
            android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="com.package.android"
                android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This is my actions.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--

<actions>

<!-- This file describes the supported actions by this app -->

<action intentName="actions.intent.START_EXERCISE">

    <!-- Each action requires at least one fulfillment that defines how the app will handle this action -->
    <!-- Define the urlTemplate in the format you define your deeplinks in AndroidManifest.xml -->

    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://com.package.android/start{?exerciseType}">

        <!-- Define how the actions parameters (intentParameter) is mapped in the urlTemplate above -->

        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="exercise.name"
            urlParameter="exerciseType"/>

    </fulfillment>

    <!-- We can define our custom inline inventory, mapping a parameter to an entity set reference -->

    <parameter name="exercise.name">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="ExerciseEntitySet"/>
    </parameter>

</action>

<action intentName="actions.intent.STOP_EXERCISE">
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://com.package.android/stop"/>
</action>

<action intentName="actions.intent.GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION">

    <!-- You can define the fulfillment mode, it can be SLICE or DEEPLINK -->
    <!-- When slice is used, make sure you are supporting slices in your app -->
    <!-- Also, not that the urlTemplate must be of the style content://{slice_provider_authority}/... -->

    <fulfillment
        fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.SLICE"
        urlTemplate="content://com.package.android.FitSliceProvider/stats{?exerciseType}">

        <!-- If a parameter is set as required, the action will only be fulfilled if the parameter is found -->
        <!-- That's why a fallback urlTemplate needs to be provided for such case. -->

        <parameter-mapping
            entityMatchRequired="true"
            intentParameter="exerciseObservation.aboutExercise.name"
            required="true"
            urlParameter="exerciseType"/>

        <!-- Note, that for the parameter above we are setting entityMatchRequired="true" -->
        <!-- This tells the Assistant to only use the entity set values to map this parameter -->
        <!-- Meaning that even if the assistant know how to identify the exercise (i.e "Climbing") -->
        <!-- if it's not defined in our entity set, the parameter won't be use. -->

    </fulfillment>

    <!-- In case the exercise name is not found we fallback to the stats deep-link inside the app -->

    <fulfillment
        fulfillmentMode="actions.fulfillment.DEEPLINK"
        urlTemplate="https://com.package.android/stats"/>

    <!-- Same as the first action, we map the parameter name with out supported entity set. -->

    <parameter name="exerciseObservation.aboutExercise.name">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="ExerciseEntitySet"/>
    </parameter>

</action>

<!-- Defines an entity set with our supported entities -->

<entity-set entitySetId="ExerciseEntitySet">

    <!-- For each entity you can specify the name, alternate names and the identifier -->
    <!-- The identifier is the value that will be added to the action uri. -->
    <!-- For our sample we map the supported entities with the class FitActivity.Type  -->

    <entity
        name="@string/activity_running"
        alternateName="@array/runningSynonyms"
        identifier="RUNNING"/>
    <entity
        name="@string/activity_walking"
        alternateName="@array/walkingSynonyms"
        identifier="WALKING"/>
    <entity
        name="@string/activity_cycling"
        alternateName="@array/cyclingSynonyms"
        identifier="CYCLING"/>
</entity-set>
```

If I try App Actions Test Tool v2.00 it doesn't find the app.
The exercise also always goes back to this format with http://schema.googleapis.com

[image]

## EDIT:

After setting actions like this:

```
<actions>
<action intentName="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://www.xelion.com/start{?feature}">
        <parameter-mapping
            intentParameter="featureType"
            urlParameter="feature"/>
    </fulfillment>

    <parameter name="featureType">
        <entity-set-reference entitySetId="EntitySet"/>
    </parameter>
</action>

<entity-set entitySetId="EntitySet">

    <!-- For each entity you can specify the name, alternate names and the identifier -->
    <!-- The identifier is the value that will be added to the action uri. -->
    <!-- For our sample we map the supported entities with the class FitActivity.Type  -->
    <entity
        name="@string/action_call"
        alternateName="@array/callSynopsis"
        identifier="CALL"/>

</entity-set>
```

I get this when pressing on update preview in App Action Test Tool:

```
App Actions Test Tool v2.0.0
        Preview Creation Error
        Status Code: 400
        Message: Precondition check failed.
        - Parameter name 'featureType' is invalid for intent 'actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE.'
        - Parameter name 'featureType' is invalid for intent 'actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE.'
```

Any ideea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first trigger the action using the App Actions Test Plugin: 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12322-app-actions-test-tool

Once you've installed the plugin, you'll find it under 'Tools' and you can define an invocation name for your app + parameters.

From then on, you can trigger it using "Ok Google".

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try this tomorrow at work.
So this means, It is not necessary to use console.actions.google.com and dialogflow? :D

Comment: Not if you're using the built-in app actions. Let me know if this works for you :)

Comment: console.actions.google.com is just for conversational actions that run on any Assistant device. You're asking about app actions, which are for starting/deeplinking to an Android app.

Comment: @Sonia I added some extra info in my questions, still doesn't recognise the commands properly

Comment: @Sonia I have accepted this as the answer, because now the app does get the deep links, and it does manage to use the actions.
I found this list with all needed / optional parameters for each type:
https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/built-in-intents/

I will look into it more, to figure out which one I should use for my case.
I need to get the Addressable of a user by name, and then call his number.
If anyone has any recommendation on which to use, I am all ears. And thanks a lot for the help so far

Comment: So, you're getting the error saying "Feature Type" is an invalid parameter because your intent parameter should have the name of the accepted parameters as outlined in the link you added above. On your actions.xml file, you wrote intentParameter="featureType", which should be intentParameter="feature". I think you had already figured this out, but I am pointing it out just in case :)

Comment: Regarding recommendations for your use case, I'm not too sure what you're trying to do. If you're trying to call a person via your app, I don't think _any_ of the built-in intents are compatible :/